# Unable to install any Operating System on HPE ProLiant ML10 Gen9

Tags: hp-proliant, bios, hpe

I have been unable to install any OS on this server.

It will bring up a grub or choice menu, but hangs after that. I just tried the ClearOS install, downloaded from the HPE link to ClearOS, it goes as far as the choice on what to do, then confirm, then a black screen.

On a Windows CD, it goes to where it starts to load, then black screen.

I downloaded the HPIP271.2019_0102.140.iso, after choosing "Intelligent Provisioning for Gen9 Servers" on the menu, will only go as far as:

"Loading kernel"

"Loading initial ramdisk"

Hangs there, goes no further.

Comment: Hi, did you tested the server with a ram test ?

Comment: Yes, Memtest86 with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to download Intelligent Provisioning. It's already on the system.

Update your firmware and possibly run the HPE Support Pack for ProLiant:
https://techlibrary.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx

Comment: I downloaded the IP by direction of HPE support. I downloaded and booted to the above mentioned link service pack. The menu comes up, after choosing either one, they both start, then the same message as in the original post. I also tried with a single stick of memory, same problem.

Comment: Please contact the reseller at this point. If you suspect there's a major issue, it may just be bad hardware.